# Чем можно заменить scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration в Java?

Tags: java, время, scala

Чем можно заменить `scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration` в `Java`? У данного класса используем только метод `toSeconds()`, если это важно для поиска решений.
Сейчас на проекте используется `scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration`, но необходимо отказаться от зависимостей от `Scala`. Поэтому ищу альтернативу в `Java`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пакет java.time в помощь, помимо еще есть [JodaTime](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/dependency-info.html)
[image: Классы java time]

Comment: Спасибо! Решением было использование класса java.time.Duration